# Будет ли эта часть кода отсечена оптимизацией ms-sql?

Tags: sql-server

Допустим есть такой код:

```
select top(1) * from 
(
     --блок 1
     select * from table1
     where col1 = '1'
     union
     --блок 2
     select * from table1
) as [data]
```

Станет ли mssql 2017 гонять код из блока 2, если код из блока один вернёт какие то значения? По идеи top(1) в первой строке должен указывать на то, что это не имеет смысла.

Comment: Скорее всего нет. Как минимум потому, что во время построение плана запроса, сервер не знает, вернет ли что-нибудь первый подзапрос. Он может только примерно оценить количество возвращаемых им строк на основе статистики, но чтобы узнать точно - ему этот запрос понадобится выполнить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL сервер выполняет запросы не построчно. Он строит общий план выполнения. План переиспользуется при следующем выполнении того же запроса, так что он должен работать на любых выбранных данных и на любых значениях параметров.

В плане в любом случае будет

- выборка из блока 1, и выборка из блока 2
- объединение результата
- выборка 1-й строки из результата

Объединение результата будет скорее всего потоковой операцией, как и выборка 1-й строки, так что реально с диска будет вычитана одна строка. Но никаких гарантий этого нет.

Как нет и гарантий, что блок 1 будет выполнен именно до блока 2 - SQL не гарантирует порядок выборки, если вы явно его не задали.

Например, оптимизатор вполне может решить, что нет смысла лезть в таблицу дважды, и просто выбросит из запроса блок 1. И если он не решает так сейчас - нет никаких гарантий, что он не решит так в следующей версии.

Т.е. ваш запрос на самом деле выбирает какую-то одну строку из table1. А не "строку с `col1 = '1'`, а если ее нет - то первую", как скорее всего задумывалось.